# nginx on docker: connection reset by peer

Tags: docker, nginx

OS: Manjaro KDE; Docker version: 19.03.12-ce

Tried searching for similar questions, but nothing helped me.

I cannot access nginx when running it on docker, or any other container, for that matter.

```
$ docker run -p 80:80 nginx
$ curl -vvv localhost
*   Trying ::1:80...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> User-Agent: curl/7.71.1
> Accept: */*
>
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

Here is the relevant part of netstat output:

```
$ sudo netstat -pnltu | grep 80
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      80884/docker-proxy
```

I also tried:

```
$ docker run -p 127.0.0.1:80:80 nginx
```

Which results in netstat:

```
$ sudo netstat -pnltu | grep 80
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      81440/docker-proxy
```

With the same result. However, if I run it like this:

```
$ docker run --network host -p 80:80 nginx
```

It works as expected. Any idea why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out!

The culprit was my (mullvad's) wireguard configuration, which adds its own iptables rules to the host machine to implement a kill-switch, forcing the entire traffic through the VPN, or dropping it.

If anyone experiences something similar, check your iptables.

```
PostUp = iptables -I OUTPUT ! -o %i -m mark ! --mark $(wg show %i fwmark) -m addrtype ! --dst-type LOCAL -j REJECT && ip6tables -I OUTPUT ! -o %i -m mark ! --mark $(wg show %i fwmark) -m addrtype ! --dst-type LOCAL -j REJECT
PreDown = iptables -D OUTPUT ! -o %i -m mark ! --mark $(wg show %i fwmark) -m addrtype ! --dst-type LOCAL -j REJECT && ip6tables -D OUTPUT ! -o %i -m mark ! --mark $(wg show %i fwmark) -m addrtype ! --dst-type LOCAL -j REJECT
```

Comment: Had the same problem. Allowing local network access with `mullvad lan set allow` solved it.